# How to retrieve the comment IP

Tags: php

I need a code that displays the IP of the person/guest that commented on my website. 
Here's the index page;

```
<?php
include "core/init.php";

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://hjalplista.comxa.com/daniel_emelie/style.Css">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Välkommen till hjälplistan!</title>



<body>
<div id="header">
<div align="right"><a href="http://www.helsingborg.se/wieselgrensskolan" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y0aiNIt.jpg"></a></div>
</div>

<div id="inside">

<center>

<div id="location"><a href='index.php'>Hem</a> - <a href='administrative/adminonlyaccess.php'><i>Admin</i></a><br><br>
</div>
<hr/>


<br>


<div id="text">
<br>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color:slategray;"><strong><center>Nr</center></strong></span></td>
            <td><span style="color:slategray;"><strong><s><center>Fått hjälp</center></s></strong></span></td>
            <td><span style="color:slategray;"><strong><center>Namn</center></strong></span></td>
            <td><span style="color:slategray;"><strong><center>Uppgift</center></strong></span></td>
            <td><span style="color:slategray;"><strong><center>IP-Adress</center></strong></span></td>
        </tr>

<?php
include "core/inc/conn.php";

mysql_select_db("comments");

$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{


     $id = $rows['id'];
     $comment_name = $rows['name'];
     $comment = $rows['comment'];



     echo"<tr><th><font color='lightgray'>$id</font></th>";
     echo"<th><font color='red'>Fungerar ej!</font></th>";
     echo "<th><u><font color='black'>$comment_name</font></u></th>";
     echo"<th><font face='black'>$comment</font></th>";
     echo"<th></th></tr>";







 }

    if(isset($_GET['error']))
{
    echo "<p>15 Bokstäver max!";

}


?>

</table>

<br><br>
</body>
<head>
<center>


</div>

<br><br>


<form action="post_comment.php" method="post">

<label> Namn: <input type="text" name="name"></label><br><br>
<label> Uppgift: <input type="text" name="comment"></label><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="post" value="Skicka">

</form>



<br><br>


<br><br>

<?php
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "<hr/>";
echo "<p> &copy; Wieselgrenskolan. All rights reserved. </p>";

?>

</head>
</html>

<html>

<div align="right">

<!-- START OF HIT COUNTER CODE -->
<br><script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.counter160.com/js.js?img=11"></script><br><a href="http://www.000webhost.com"><img src="http://www.counter160.com/images/11/left.png" alt="Free web hosting" border="0" align="textright"></a><a href="http://www.hosting24.com"><img alt="Web hosting" src="http://www.counter160.com/images/11/right.png" border="0" align="texttop"></a>
<!-- END OF HIT COUNTER CODE -->

</div>
</html>
```

And it's supposed to be in the `echo "<th></th></tr>";`. Do I need a MySQL table for that?

I've created a index in mysql called ''commentip'' but I don't know how to fix the missing parts.

Comment: What should that ip address be good for? Its a dynamic address anyway in 99% of all cases. Anyways: take a look at phps "superglobals", you find some request details in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: I need it to be able to ban their IP's.

Comment: *"How to retrieve the comment IP*" and *"I need it to be able to ban their IP's"* are two different animals altogether. Banning IP addresses is not always reliable.

Comment: What code is writing comments to the database? If it isn't saving the IP address with the comment, that information will not be stored anywhere, and there is no way to retrieve it.

Comment: Well I'm not creating a high-secure website and this website wasn't supposed to be a difficult one, I just need the IP to be displayed of the comment to be able to ban them, I'm doing a simple website for my teacher.

Comment: You would not believe the results Google gave while searching for "how to ban ip address php"; use it.

Comment: @duskwuff, Do you want the code of my post comment code?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've got the code to be able to ban, I just need to get the IP address, displayed on a table. I just need the (get IP) code. :/

Comment: Smistry's answer is what you should use. @user3504482 just do `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding what you mean by "get IP code... displayed on a table". You will need to be more precise.

Comment: Do you mean, you have an IP (or list of) stored in your DB and you would like to echo it in an HTML table?

Comment: @Fred-ii- If or when someone sends a comment, then it'll display his; ID/Number | Name | Comment | IP | I just don't know how to get the REMOTE_ADDR of the user that commented. :/

Comment: You will need to first store the IP in a row associated with the user's id, then simply (fetch/loop) and add a row in your HTML table fetched from your DB. I.e.: `$user=$row['user']; $IP=$row['ip']; echo $user . "\n"; echo $IP . "\n";`

Comment: Yes, exactly, @Fred-ii-, but the problem is, I don't have that code.
I need a code, that will save the user's comment's IP into my DB/MySQl and then I'd like to echo it out on my website! :)

Comment: banning based on ip, is like banning based on shirt colour( many people have same shirt colour, and changing shirt is easy)

Comment: `INSERT into table_name (id,ip,comment) VALUES ($id,$IP,$comment)` is the basic INSERT syntax. Using `$IP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: You could also add an extra colum called `allowed` and automatically make it as `YES` for example when writing a new entry to DB. Then, when you call your script, you would add a `WHERE` clause to the effect of `WHERE banned='NO'` to allow a user --- Your "banned" addresses would hold a `YES` instead of a `NO`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, is there any chance you could help me out with just a simple line of code, like just really simple.
Right now, I used $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; but now it only shows the 5 first numbers of the REMOTE_ADDR, without dots, for example; 12123 any help?

Comment: What is your column set to? VARCHAR, INT, other? Also, your column's length will also play a role. It needs to be a minimum of 16. If it's lower, set it to 25.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, it's an INT(11), should I change it?

Comment: Yes, change it to VARCHAR(25) just to be safe because there are dots and will not be interpreted correctly if set to INT.

Comment: I've got it right now, there's a problem that will be annoying to fix, currently everything's stable and it works!
Oh by the way, had to change it to VARCHAR(100), though it works! :)
Thanks.

Comment: Great, so problem solved then? @user3504482

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP in php in most cases using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` However if they are using a proxy or you are using a reverse proxy like cloudflare or incapsula then you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.

Comment: Hmm, well I've tried many different ways, and it didn't work. :/

Comment: What do you mean bu it didn't work did you get any errors? Did you try a simple `print_r($_SERVER)` in a seperate file to see what is there?

Comment: A lot of things, but I just need the REMOTE_ADDR.